# So I have a bound service, is there a way that I can use the service in the onResume of an activity?

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

Code:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), UserAPIService.class);
    getActivity().bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    mService.fetchUserInfo();
}

private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                   IBinder service) {
        UserAPIService.LocalBinder binder = (UserAPIService.LocalBinder) service;
        mService = binder.getService();
        mBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        mBound = false;
    }
};
```

The user info is attempted to be fetched, but the service is null because it hasn't been bound yet. What is the best way to go about this? I could make the API call in the onServiceConnected method, but there has to be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the

```
mService.fetchUserInfo();
```

inside the method

```
onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,IBinder service)
```

You cannot get the service instance unless your service is bound and it may require some time .  onStart() is better place to bind a service.

Comment: What if I create a singleton in the application class of the api service?

Comment: @Nick: If the service depends on the binding, then that would be a good idea, to prevent it being destroyed when the `Activity` is restarted due to configuration changes. You will have to manage the binding lifecycle yourself appropriately in that case though.